# Performing function on each array element, returning results to new array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq

I'm a complete Linq newbie here, so forgive me for a probably quite simple question.

I want to perform an operation on every element in an array, and return the result of each of these operations to a new array.

For example, say I have an array or numbers and a function ToWords() that converts the numbers to their word equivalents, I want to be able to pass in the numbers array, perform the ToWords() operation on each element, and pass out a string[]

I know it's entirely possible in a slightly more verbose way, but in my Linq adventures I'm wondering if it's doable in a nice one-liner.

Comment: Is there something you have tried? Any pieces of code that you wrote but failed to do what you needed?

Comment: Is the output one string per number ("one hundred and one") or multiple strings per number ("one", "hundred", "and", "one")?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) to transform one sequence into another one, and [`ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) to create an array from the result:

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3 };
string[] strings = numbers.Select(x => ToWords(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Ah, how on earth did I miss this? Thanks! :)

Comment: Didn't know about `Select`, always used `ToList().ConvertAll()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

It's pretty straight forward. Just use the [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) method:

```
var results = array.Select(ToWords).ToArray();
```

Note that unless you need an array you don't have to call `ToArray`. Most of the time you can use lazy evaluation on an `IEnumerable<string>` just as easily.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different approaches - you can use [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548891.aspx) extension method or you can use [select clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb384087.aspx):

```
var numbers = new List<int>();
var strings1 = from num in numbers select ToWords(num);
var strings2 = numbers.Select(ToWords);
```

both of them will return `IEnumerable<>`, which you can cast as you need (for example, with `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()`).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this :

```
    public static string[] ProcessStrings(int[] intList)
    {
        return Array.ConvertAll<int, string>(intList, new Converter<int, string>(
        delegate(int number)
        {
            return ToWords();
        }));
    }
```

If it is a list then :

```
    public static List<string> ProcessStrings(List<int> intList)
    {
        return intList.ConvertAll<string>(new Converter<int, string>(
         delegate(int number)
         {
              return ToWords();
         }));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight simple:

```
string[] wordsArray = array.ToList().ConvertAll(n => ToWords(n)).ToArray();
```

If you are OK with Lists, rather than arrays, you can skip `ToList()` and `ToArray()`.

Lists are much more flexible than arrays, I see no reason on earth not to use them, except for specific cases.